# MySql: Matching sold products to bought products

Tags: mysql

Okay, lets assume you have a shop and you bought some products for reselling like:

```
purchases:
id   date    amount   product     buying-price
1    1. Sep   10x     "Product A"     $3,70
2    1. Oct    5x     "Product A"     $3,80
3    1. Nov    2x     "Product A"     $3,50
```

I want to sell the products on a "first-in-first-out"-basis, so the first 10 products are sold out of the purchase from 1. Sep, the next 5 products from the purchase from 1. Oct and so on.

The Q is: Is there a SQL-statement which is able to tell me the purchase-id based on sold products? Examples:

```
8 products sold so far => id=1
12 products sold so far => id=2
16 products sold so far => id=3
```

Comment: So where is the number of products for each id?

Comment: looking schema I think purchase id is auto increment so how `8 products sold so far => id=1`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what do you want to do with this query. 
Here is an example for one product (if `ID's` are increasing with `Date`) :

```
select min(id) 
from T as T1 
where 
  Product='Product A'
  AND
  (SELECT SUM(Amount) from T where Product='Product A' and id<=T1.id)
      >= <Amount you need to test>
```